# Codeception and Docker, doing it right

Tags: php, docker, codeception

I am new to the container world and I am trying to make a codeception container. I saw a boilerplate on dockerhub "codeception/codeception"

https://hub.docker.com/r/codeception/codeception/~/dockerfile/

So I copied the Dockerfile to the root of my project

And I did a `docker -t build coolbeans/codeception .`

And I did a `docker run -d -p 80:80  coolbeans/codeception`

Then I got this error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error:
>   container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"codecept\": executable file not found in $PATH".

This is the snippet from the `Dockerfile` where It seems the error is coming from:

```
ENV PATH /repo:${PATH}
ENTRYPOINT ["codecept"]
```

Answer (score 0):

you should probably make your ENTRYPOINT fully qualified and check if codecept is executable.

Comment: that is just a typo on my description. Sorry i corrected it, but that is not the issue. Thanks for pointing that out